# Print Key Value from Selected Item in Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to find weapon1 from the dictionary and then print its 'key' and 'value' pairs so I can refer to them separately. This works for all items in the dictionary but when I want just one I cant seem to make it work.

```
inventoryitems = {"weapon1": 45, "weapon2": 5}

selecteditem = inventoryitems["weapon1"]
print(selecteditem)

for k, v in selecteditem():
    print(k, v)
```

I get this error code:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I understand so far that its calling the value for weapon1 (which is 'int') but I want to call both the key and value from the found item in the dictionary. Any help on this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
inventoryitems = {"weapon1": 45, "weapon2": 5}

selecteditem = inventoryitems["weapon1"]
# by doing this you have assigned the value of key( = weapon1) to the variable selecteditem
# since this value was int now your selecteditem is int

print(selecteditem) # will print 45

# but now you are try to call selecteditem which is an int, and you can't call an int so python will give you an error

'''
for k, v in selecteditem():
    print(k, v)

'''
```

```
# instead do this 

selecteditem, selecteditem_value = 'weapon1', inventoryitems["weapon1"]

print('you selected {0} and its power is {1}'.format(selecteditem, selecteditem_value)) #you selected weapon1 and its power is 45
```

edit:

```
inventoryitems = {"weapon1": 45, "weapon2": 5}

def user_selection( item_selected):
    print('you selected {0} and its power is {1}'.format(item_selected, inventoryitems[item_selected])) #you selected weapon1 and its power is 45


user_selection( 'weapon1') # you selected weapon1 and its power is 45
```

Comment: thank you Tanmay, this is close to what I want. Is there a way to map this to just one variable so I can pass this into another function? @Tanmay jain

Comment: @JamesVella I am not sure what you are trying to do, see the edited answer.

Comment: Thank you @Tanmay jain, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @JamesVella happy to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

your `selecteditem` is the value 45, you then try to loop through `selecteditem` but it's only an integer hence the error:

```
for k, v in inventoryitems.items():
    print(k, v)
```

Comment: this lists all the items, however I want to refer to only the weapon1, so when the character selects this item I can refer to the key and the value separately. "You have selected 'weapon1' which does '45' damage for example @Sven H.

Comment: In which case I would say do `selected_weapon = "weapon1"` and `weapon_damage = inventoryitems[selected_weapon]` so you have them both stored in variables for later

Comment: thank you @Sven H. I was looking for something to fit my specific situation, I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the key `weapon1`, you really only need the value, which is already stored in `selectedItem` since you assigned `inventoryitems["weapon1"]` to it. There's no need for any further call or iteration here.

Comment: I would like to refer to both key and value pairs separetely. see below my comment about how a character chooses a weapon and then i can use the key name and value for separate functions @blhsing

Comment: You can easily do that with `print("You have selected '{}' which does '{}' damage".format('weapon1', inventoryitems["weapon1"])`.